# Is this the correct proof of absolute convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Absolute convergence theorem says that if $\sum |a_n|$ is convergent, so is $\sum a_n$

We have by triangle inequality :

$$|a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n|\le |a_1|+|a_2|+\cdots+|a_n|$$

Now if $S_n$ is the sequence of partial sums of $\sum a_n$ and $P_n$ is sequence of partial sums of $\sum|a_n|$ and assuming $P_{\infty}=L$, we have:

$$|S_n|\le P_n$$

Taking limit we get:

$$\left|\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n\right|\le L$$

Hence:

$$-L \le S_{\infty}\le L$$

Hence $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

Comment: How do you know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n$ exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Show instead that the Cauchy criterion is satisfied using

$$|S_m-S_n|=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k\right| \leqslant \sum_{k=n+1}^m |a_k|$$

Comment: You’ve only proved that $S_n$ is bounded but not necesarily convergent.

Comment: A non-convergent sequence like $x_n= (-1)^n$ is bounded as $|x_n| \leqslant y_n = 1$. Here $y_n$ is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

We can use that

$$b_n=-|a_n|\le a_n \le |a_n|=c_n$$

and conclude that

$$\sum |a_n|<\infty \implies \sum a_n<\infty$$

indeed $\sum (c_n - b_n)$ converges and therefore since

$$0\le a_n-b_n \le c_n-b_n$$

also $\sum (a_n - b_n)$ converges and since

$$\sum a_n = \sum(b_n+(a_n-b_n))= \sum b_n+\sum (a_n-b_n)$$

we conclude that $\sum a_n$ is the sum of two convergent series.

Comment: i like this proof too

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma Yes it makes use only of basic facts and it is quite generale. If $b_n\le a_n \le c_n$ with $\sum b_n$ and $\sum c_n$ convergent then $\sum a_n$ converges.